# How do I make the word 'contents' central when using \tableofcontents?

Tags: table-of-contents

How do I make the word 'contents' central when using `\tableofcontents`?

I am using `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` and it does not seem to work when I try something like `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}`

Is it possible to get around this problem?

To give some code: This is the existing frame I am using.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% emulate the plain style
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{% a rule at the bottom
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[L]{All rights reserved}%
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\title{A paper}
\author{A. Uthor}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{first page}

\tableofcontents

\section{section1}
\lipsum[1-20] % fill some pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `fancyhdr` does the headings and the footers of pages but not headings of chapters -- there's a misunderstanding. Do you want to center the ToC title only, but not the list entries

Comment: I've edited your post and you've edited my 'improvements' away... :-(

Comment: I only need the ToC, however it would be helpful to know how to center all sections too.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't realise you had tried to edit it!

Comment: @user88473 Please see my answer below to see an option to center all section titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty method: Assuming you never use `\contentsname` somewhere else you could use

```
\let\origcontentsname\contentsname
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\origcontentsname\hfill}
```

This stores the old name to `\origcontentsname` and you can still use the old definition in a `\renewcommand{}`

`\hfill\origcontentsname\hfill` centers the text then by filling (`\hfill`) the available whitespace.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% emulate the plain style
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{% a rule at the bottom
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[L]{All rights reserved}%
}

\let\origcontentsname\contentsname
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\origcontentsname\hfill}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\title{A paper}
\author{A. Uthor}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\tableofcontents

\section{section1}
\lipsum[1-20] % fill some pages

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Only works if `\contentsname` was previously declared. I'd perhaps use something like `AtBeginDocument`, to prevent overwriting the macro between your redefinition and `\begin{document}`..

Comment: @1010011010: `\contentsname` is declared by most classes, so this is in general no issue. If somebody thinks he must redefine `\contentsname` again, that's his/her decision.  In the same way Gonzalo's solution would fail if there's no `\contentsname` defined.

Comment: I was more so referring to user-made redeclarations, but yeah, that's an issue too. heheh

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch `\tableofcontents` and center the title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% emulate the plain style
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{% a rule at the bottom
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[L]{All rights reserved}%
}

\pagestyle{plain}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\contentsname}
  {\hfill\contentsname\hfill}
  {}
  {}

\title{A paper}
\author{A. Uthor}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\tableofcontents

\section{section1}
\lipsum[1-20] % fill some pages

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to center *all* section titles,

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\centering}
```

Answer (score 2):

Load `tocloft` and put

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil \Large\bfseries}
```

in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% emulate the plain style
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{% a rule at the bottom
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[L]{All rights reserved}%
}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil \Large\bfseries}

\begin{document}
  \title{A paper}
  \author{A. Uthor}
  \maketitle
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}
  \tableofcontents
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `etoolbox` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\let\olssection\section
\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\centering}{}{}
\oldtableofcontents
\let\section\olssection
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% emulate the plain style
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{% a rule at the bottom
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[L]{All rights reserved}%
}



\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\title{A paper}
\author{A. Uthor}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\tableofcontents

\section{section1}
\lipsum[1-20] % fill some pages

\end{document}
```

[image]